# Making ImageGallery of private Images in S3 Client android

Tags: java, android, caching, amazon-s3, picasso

I am trying to create an imageGallery of my S3 Bucket in my android application. My images are private so i won't be having any specific link for each image.

For Such private images , amazon has a link generator,

```
s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, expiration);
```

It generates a URL with let's say 1 hour or 2 min expiration set by us.

Now for easy memory caching and stuff, i can either use volley or Picasso or many other such easy loading libraries.

However there is this catch. I want to cache these images in memory. But all i have is dynamic link.

How can i make Picasso or any other library use dynamic link to cache?

As per my information, the libraries use Url as "key" to cache, is that correcT? if so how can i save these images so i can use these images later even when i am offline, again, i have dynamic link so url will be changing every instant so maybe i need to save them with the Key i am passing to s3Client.

What is the solution.

Comment: Hey @Muhammad Umar, I have problem in loading the url. I have generated the signed url using "generatePresignedUrl(Constants.S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, expiration)" and tried loading it by using picasso , but it's not quite seems to be working. When I tried that link on browser I got "signature error "

Comment: @Muhammad Umar i have same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422555/how-to-load-image-from-aws-with-picasso-with-private-access?noredirect=1#comment79803371_46422555
please post answer if you have solved above problem

Answer (score 0):

Latest `Picasso` version adopts setting network policies. Probably, you need to set `NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE` for the `Picasso.Request` builder:

```
Picasso.with(this)
            .load(s3Url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(imageView);
```

Regarding the caching, you might want to set expiration time to `CacheControl` of the Picasso `OkHttpClient`, to be same as the S3 links.

Comment: @Muhammad Umar i have same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422555/how-to-load-image-from-aws-with-picasso-with-private-access?noredirect=1#comment79803371_46422555 please post answer if you have solved above problem